# How to rotate door smoothly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game where a door has to rotate -90 degrees smoothly. I've tried lots of different things, but i can't make it work.

```
public float degrees = -90f;

public Transform door;

private void update()
{
    door.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, degrees, Space.Self);
}
```

How do i make it rotate smoothly and not just snap into place?

Comment: look at slerp...

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution

```
public float degrees = -90f;
    public float rotationDuration = 5f;

    public Transform door;

    private float startTime;
    private bool isOpenningDoor;

    private void OpenDoor()
    {
        startTime = Time.time;
        door.transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.zero;
        isOpenningDoor = true;
    }

    private void update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))//for testing
        {
            OpenDoor();
        }
        if(isOpenningDoor)
        {
            float ratio = (Time.time - startTime)/rotationDuration;//percentage of total rotation
            if(ratio >= 1f)//when you reached max rotation
            {
                ratio = 1f;
                isOpenningDoor = false;//Stop extra rotation
            }
            door.transform.Rotate(0f, 0f, ratio * degrees, Space.Self);
        }
    }
```

The open time is 5 secs in the example. If you want to do a lot of small programmer side animations I suggest [Dotween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php) for some nice easing and quick implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) and [Slerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) method. Try this:

```cs
using System.Collection;

...

public Transform door;
public float degrees = -90f;
public float someSpeed = 0.08f;

IEnumerator OpenDoor ()
{
    while (door.transform.localEulerAngles.y > degrees)
    {
        door.transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(door.transform.localEulerAngles
            , new Vector3(0, degress - 0.2f, 0), someSpeed);

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    yield break;
}
```

And where you need, just call `StartCoroutine(OpenDoor());`.

Hope that's what you want.